# How to update an object item via loop

Tags: node.js, object, async.js

I try to add an property to an object. I have a list with customers, and for every customer I want to add an array with mails which are send to that customer.

But I can't add it to the existing object. What i'm doing wrong?

```
crmuser.find().exec(function(err, crmusers){
    console.log(crmusers);

    //LOG result
    [ { _id: 59563a7181438f4db8193379,
       emailName: 'Donald Duck',
       shop: 'dd',
       moreproperties: '',
       email: 'donald@duck.com',
    } ]

    async.each(Object.keys(crmusers), function(key, callback){
      mailService.getLogs({to: crmusers[key].email, typeMail: "CRM"}, function(err, result){
        console.log("res", result); // here we have the result from the mailService.getLogs() function


        crmusers[key]["sendMail"] = {result}; //Here I try to add a new property to the object

        console.log("USERR", crmusers[key]); // And here I can see that the property is not added
        callback();
      })
    }, function(){
      status = 200;
      response = {message: 'OK', crmusers};
      return res.status(status).json(response);
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you log `err` and check for any errors?

Comment: Your code works well for me. Possibly multiple elements with same id in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through values with an `each` or `forEach` you can use a `map` function to return a new object from each item in your users array. As you're users variable is an object not an array the best async method to use would be `mapValues`:

```
const users = {
 john: { email: 'test@test.com' },
 anne: { email: 'test@test.com' }
};

async.mapValues(users, function (user, key, callback) {
  mailService.getLogs({to: user.email, typeMail: "CRM"}, function(err, result){
    if (err) callback(err);
    user["sendMail"] = result;
    callback(null, user);
  })
}, function(err, result) {
    // result is now a new map of your users
    // {
    //   john: { sendMail: 'result', email: 'test@test.com' },
    //   anne: { sendMail: 'result', email: 'test@test.com' }
    // };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined` error on `async.mapValues(crmusers), function(user, key, callback){` crmusers is an object which we request from mongoose. Like `crmusers.find().exec(function(err, crmusers)`

Comment: Edited my question with the find line and the result of crmusers

Comment: Add a console of the cmsusers object.

Comment: see my question. I have added the log result als comment in the code